# How to renew subscriptions after IISRESET?

Tags: nservicebus, publish-subscribe

This is my scenario:

- Web application with a self-hosted bus (publisher)
- Windows service with NServiceBus.Host.exe (subscriber)

Imagine that trigger an IISRESET (never mind on the why I have to do that) that makes the bus re-initialize and lose the subscriptions that already had. I'm using MsmqSubscriptionStorage and the publisher (web app) implements the IAuthorizeSubscriptions interface.

How can I renew the subscriptions and also call the AuthorizeSubscribe()? Is that possible? What's your suggestion to this scenario?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If NServiceBus is properly using MsmqSubscriptionStorage, then after iisreset, the bus should initialize and load the existing subscriptions from the configured storage queue.  This queue name can either be set by configuration or, if omitted, should default to a name based on an assembly plus "_storage".  However, having never used this from a web application, I don't know what that would be in that scenario, since there is no class that implements IConfigureThisEndpoint.

That said, trying to publish an event from a web application is a very icky business, and it's [generally advised that you avoid just that](http://www.make-awesome.com/2010/10/why-not-publish-nservicebus-messages-from-a-web-application/).

Comment: David, thanks for the answer and many thanks for the link you provided. Didn't know that!